# push an element to each array in a multidimentional array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here's my array

```
$myArr  = array(array('one', 'two'), array('one', 'two'));
```

I would like add an element to every array inside the **$myArr**. I dont wanna loop over each array inside and add that element. Is there any quicker way to achieve this using **array_map** or **array_walk**.. preferably **with one line of code**?

Result array should be like

```
$myArr  = array(array('one', 'two','three'), array('one', 'two','three'));
```

Thanks a bunch

Got it, Kudos to [@strager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39992/strager)

```
$myvar = 'Three';

$myArr = array_map(function ($subarray) {  global $myvar; $subarray[] = $myvar;   return $subarray;}, $myArr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($myArr, create_function('&$subarray', '$subarray[] = "three";'));
```

With `array_map`:

```
$myArr = array_map(create_function('$subarray', '$subarray[] = "three"; return $subarray;'), $myArr);
```

With anonymous functions an `array_map` (untested; I don't have access to PHP5.3):

```
$myArr = array_map(function ($subarray) {
    $subarray[] = "three";
    return $subarray;
}, $myArr);
```

Or of course, the better solution (for PHP < 5.3):

```
function pushToEndOfSubarrays($array, $item) {
    $ret = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
        $subarray[] = $item;
        $ret[$key] = $subarray;
    }

    return $ret;
}

$myArr = pushToEndOfSubarrays($myArr, 'three');
```

Comment: I'm using : array_walk($myArr, create_function('&$subarray', '$subarray[] = "three";')); How can i pass my element varible to add into create_function? Its a dynamic value rather than text like 'three'

Comment: @Naresh, That's where things get tricky.  Just use one of the last two suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use function array_push() for push array into array

```
int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $var [, mixed $... ] );
```

This may help you as your requirements.

thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't one still require a loop for this? otherwise it would simply append the value to the end of the parent array and not the children.

Comment: The questioner wants to push one element to each array inside `$myArr`.  They don't seem to want to push a new array to `$myArr`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i just want to add an element to all arrays inside my main array.. not pushing an element into array