# PHP Add element to every sub array of multi dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like that

```
array(
     [0] => array(
               'id' => 1,
               'title' => 'title 1',
     ),
     [1] => array(
               'id' => 10,
               'title' => 'title 10',
     ),
     [2] => array(
               'id' => 11,
               'title' => 'title 11',
     ),
     [...]
);
```

I want to add an element to all the sub array. It's the same element i'm adding. so the new array will look like :

```
array(
     [0] => array(
               'id' => 1,
               'title' => 'title 1',
               'type'  => 'bag',
     ),
     [1] => array(
               'id' => 10,
               'title' => 'title 10',
               'type'  => 'bag',
     ),
     [2] => array(
               'id' => 11,
               'title' => 'title 11',
               'type'  => 'bag',
     ),
     [...]
);
```

<del>Is there a way to do it **without iterating** on the the first array?</del>
It's gonna be a big array. I'm looking for the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Well, internally iteration is going to happen even if you used something like `array_map()`

Comment: Or by `without iterating` do you mean you just don't want a multiline foreach loop?

Comment: It's an array from with results from a db (up to a few hundreds). I assume a foreach loop will be slow. hence without iterating. I meant a fast way.

Comment: @chaft: You *assume*. Have you tested it? An array with a few hundred (or thousand, for that matter) elements in it will be iterated in a few milliseconds. And even `array_walk()` iterates the array internally, there is no magic involved. ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364997/2943403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever speed one might hope to gain by using array_walk, is lost with function overhead. Since you stated in your comments that the array is a result of a db query, **you can simply include the `bag` value in your result set by adding** `SELECT 'bag' AS 'type'` **to your SQL statement.**

```
$start = 0; $end = 0;

$orig = array(
    array('id' => 1,  'title' => 'title 1'),
    array('id' => 10, 'title' => 'title 10'),
    array('id' => 11, 'title' => 'title 11')
);

// A
$start = microtime(true);
for ($a=0; $a<1000; $a++) {
    $els1 = $orig;
    array_walk($els1, function(&$val, $key){$val['type'] = 'bag';});
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'A: ', $end - $start,  "<br />\n";

// B
$start = microtime(true);
for ($b=0; $b<1000; $b++) {
    $els2 = $orig;
    foreach ($els2 as &$el) {
        $el['type'] = 'bag';
    }
    unset($el);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'B: ', $end - $start,  "<br />\n";

/* output:

A: 0.0076138973236084
B: 0.0047528743743896

A: 0.0075309276580811
B: 0.0045361518859863

A: 0.0075531005859375
B: 0.062379837036133

A: 0.0075340270996094
B: 0.0044951438903809

A: 0.0074868202209473
B: 0.0044751167297363

A: 0.0076088905334473
B: 0.0048189163208008

*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Logically, no, there isn't any way to do it without iterating the parent array. <s>But you can make it less painful by using `array_walk()`.</s> EDIT: benchmark shows array_walk (or array-_map) is slower by a third, so I take this back.

Comment: How to make it less painful with `array_walk` in php < 5.3?

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn: so you think that creating additional function **less painful** than to traverse it by `foreach` with **1 line**?

Comment: @zerkms yes. `array_walk` iterates internally, without opcode processing overhead. Try this and see how long it runs: `foreach(range(1,1000000) as $i) {};` (yes, empty loop taking XX seconds. Rewrite that to `for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {}` and it will take even more).

Comment: @NoICE: dude, you told about `array_walk()` as less painful solution. So I asked you how in php < 5.3 it can be less painful. Where `for` vs `foreach` came from?! Have you seen the answer above yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436642/251311 ??? `iterates internally` -- yes, it does iterate internally, **BUT** it calls a function. Function call is **much more expensive** than just assignment

Comment: @zerkms less painful [than iterating it manually -> and what keywords we use for iterating? for and foreach.]. Also, by "less painful" I ment "less painful for the server, for performance hit". Function call in php is fast and in this case it is done internally, too (though I don't have that confirmed, maybe foreach with reference assignment is faster for this purpose. As I think about it it should. Wait a minute, I will benchmark it. ... Oh I've just noticed that someone already did that, so you are right, foreach is faster for this purpose.. even if it is just by 3 miliseconds :D ).

Comment: @NoICE: even though it is faster for just 3ms (which in fact is **37%**) it takes less keystrokes and is *more readable* (which is more important, than timings)

Answer (score 3):

From a simple/clean code point of view this solution suits:

```
$orig = array(
array('id' => 1,  'title' => 'title 1'),
array('id' => 10, 'title' => 'title 10'),
array('id' => 11, 'title' => 'title 11'));

foreach($orig as $key => $value)
{
    $value['type'] = 'bag';
    $orig[$key] = $value;   
}
```