# how to edit row inside array of objects in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

i have a var that holds an array of objects. `$object`:

```
Array
(
[0] => First_Model Object
    (
        [_id:protected] => 988198
        [_status:protected] => some string here
        [_user_id:protected] => 18289
    )

[1] => Second_Model Object
    (
        [_id:protected] => 566198
        [_status:protected] => some string here
        [_user_id:protected] => 18290
    )
....
```

if i do:

```
<?php foreach($object as $row): ?>
<?php echo $row->status(); ?>
<?php endforeach: ?>
```

i get: `some string here`

what i want to do is to edit `$row->status()`, maybe use `ucwords` or something on this string and them place it back in the `$object` so that when i do the loop i get the changed result.

i could alter the result inside the foreach loop but i want my code to be clean.

so i need to grab `$object->status` do something with it then place it back on the `$object` then ill have the modified result..

any ideas on how to place the modified string inside the array of objects?

thanks

Comment: Why is using a `foreach` loop not *clean*?

Comment: @webbiedave Theory is: when you use specialized function (such as `array_walk`), in future it may work in parallel threads. And I guess php provides some kind of optimalization for calling function via this function (at least callback are called from C source (`array_walk` is implemented in C), not via interpreted (slower) code).

Comment: @Vyktor: Using `array_walk` is [almost always slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436261/php-add-element-to-every-sub-array-of-multi-dimension-array/8436642#8436642) than just `foreach`-ing. Future parallel thread? By the time PHP can do that, we'll all have flying cars :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), all necessary examples are in documentation :)

I would also create interface, that would declare methods: `setStatus` and `getStatus` and use

```
if( !($item1 instanceof YourInterface)){
    throw new Exception(...);
}
```